# Connection of Mule 4 with Weblogic queue

Tags: mule, weblogic, esb, mule4

How to connect MULE 4 with weblogic 12c queue. Able to connect to active MQ successfully but while trying to connect to weblogic I'm not able to find maven dependency.

Comment: Can you share you console output to see what depedencies are missing

Answer (score 0):

For Weblogic 12c JMS Use the below jars in Mule dependency.

1) weblogic.jar
2) wlthint3client.jar